# Pip Equivalent to Bundler Local Override

Tags: python, pip

In Ruby, when I am simultaneously developing a library and an application, I can use Bundler's *local override* feature to make the application use my local copy of the library instead of trying to fetch from Github on my system. This is very convenient.

```
# Given my application's Gemfile with this one line...
gem 'mylib', :github => 'smackesey/mylib', :branch => 'master'

# I can run this once in my shell...
bundle config local.mylib /path/to/mylib

# And now on my system, the app will use the copy at /path/to/my/lib
```

I am now facing a similar situation in Python. `requirements.txt` is essentially equivalent to the Gemfile, but does `pip` support local override functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install an editable version of your library with `pip install -e git+ssh://...#egg=package-name` (substitute [your repository URL](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#vcs-support) here). This will create a checkout of your library and put it into the python module search path. If you already have a local copy of the library, executing `pip install -e /path/to/your/checkout` will do the same. If a non-editable version of your library is already installed, you may need to pass `--upgrade` to pip.

Behind the scenes, pip will create a file called `easy-install.pth` in your `site-packages` directory, which then contains a line with the full path to the checkout of your library. You can read more about `.pth` files [in the official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html); for more pip options, see [the official pip documentation](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html), [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs) is the part about [editable installs](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#editable-installs).